# Hadoop 'copyFromLocal: Can not create a Path from a null string' error

Tags: docker, hadoop

I have a question about this error on hadoop. 
I want to copy the txt file from my local drive to hadoop folder wcdata (to run wordcount example on hadoop). 
I tried `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\demo\demoinput.txt /wcdata/demoinput.txt` as well as `hadoop fs -put C:\demo\demoinput.txt /wcdata/demoinput.txt`
This both give me an error `'Can not create a Path from a null string'`. 
I don't see any null string in my path tho... 
Can someone please tell me what I should do?

Comment: You have Hadoop commands in windows rather than volume mount into your Docker container and running Hadoop command there?

Comment: i can run docker on cmd but i dont know how to write hadoop commands there  afterwards.. isn't that i need to have hadoop on my window to be able to write commands on cmd?

Comment: You can `docker exec` into a terminal of the running container. If you are not sure how to do that, I would suggest maybe not using Docker